# Invalid HTML (img: 'src' must be non-empty) when using "attr-binding" with knockout.js

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js, w3c-validation

I love knockout.js and I use is very often.

But when I use the "attr-binding" for an img’s `src` or `alt` attribute, like

```
data-bind="attr: { src: photo.src, alt: 'description'}"
```

The W3C-validator says that’s invalid HTML:

> Bad value for attribute `src` on element `img`: Must be non-empty.

And they are right, because the attributes are empty until the model was bound and executed.

Is there any other workaround than providing a link to a wrong image? Or in other words, is it a real problem somebody has been facing before?

Comment: Did you define an alt attribute for the image? How do exactly pass the src value?

Comment: i realised its not really a question because theres no real answer to it, what i want to express is, the src and alt tag get their values when js is executed and initial theyre empty, so knockout produces invalid html until js is executed

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<img src="#" alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: photo.src, alt: 'description'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this -

```
data-bind="attr: { src: photo.src || 'default.jpg' }"
```

Fiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/jAYPL/